# flutter localauth : Required security features not enabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using local_auth: ^1.1.3 and using

```
await _localAuthentication.authenticate(
          localizedReason: S.of(Get.context!).main_pass_view_body,
          // "Please authenticate to complete your transaction",
          androidAuthStrings: androidMessages,
          iOSAuthStrings: iosMessages,
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: true);
```

but I got this error when I call `authenticate` method :

```
PlatformException(NotAvailable, Required security features not enabled, null, null)
```

I expect, when user did not configure finger print on mobile ,when tapped on Authenticate button ,default biometric dialog open and user could do configuration on mobile phone but I got that error.
It should open default biometric dialog to transfer user to configuration part of mobile, but I got error.

I also added     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>` in manifest.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and flutter sdk

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by catching the `PlatformException` exeption and checking for `canCheckBiometrics` and `isDeviceSupported()` before calling `authenticate()` method.

This is the snippet of code:

```dart
if (await auth.canCheckBiometrics && await auth.isDeviceSupported()){
    try {
        if(await auth.authenticate(
          ... // authenticate configuration
           )){
               // authenticated
        }
      } on PlatformException catch (exception) {
        // catch the exception
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
  _SupportState _supportState = _SupportState.unknown;
  bool? _canCheckBiometrics;
  List<BiometricType>? _availableBiometrics;
  String _authorized = 'Not Authorized';
  bool _isAuthenticating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth.isDeviceSupported().then(
          (isSupported) => setState(() => _supportState = isSupported
          ? _SupportState.supported
          : _SupportState.unsupported),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _checkBiometrics() async {
    late bool canCheckBiometrics;
    try {
      canCheckBiometrics = await auth.canCheckBiometrics;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      canCheckBiometrics = false;
      print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _canCheckBiometrics = canCheckBiometrics;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAvailableBiometrics() async {
    late List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics;
    try {
      availableBiometrics = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      availableBiometrics = <BiometricType>[];
      print(e);
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _availableBiometrics = availableBiometrics;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate() async {
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = true;
        _authorized = 'Authenticating';
      });
      authenticated = await auth.authenticate(
          localizedReason: 'Let OS determine authentication method',
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: true);
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = false;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = false;
        _authorized = "Error - ${e.message}";
      });
      return;
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(
            () => _authorized = authenticated ? 'Authorized' : 'Not Authorized');
  }

  Future<void> _authenticateWithBiometrics() async {
    bool authenticated = false;
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = true;
        _authorized = 'Authenticating';
      });
      authenticated = await auth.authenticate(
          localizedReason:
          'Scan your fingerprint (or face or whatever) to authenticate',
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: true,
          biometricOnly: true);
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = false;
        _authorized = 'Authenticating';
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      setState(() {
        _isAuthenticating = false;
        _authorized = "Error - ${e.message}";
      });
      return;
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    final String message = authenticated ? 'Authorized' : 'Not Authorized';
    setState(() {
      _authorized = message;
    });
  }

  void _cancelAuthentication() async {
    await auth.stopAuthentication();
    setState(() => _isAuthenticating = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                if (_supportState == _SupportState.unknown)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else if (_supportState == _SupportState.supported)
                  Text("This device is supported")
                else
                  Text("This device is not supported"),
                Divider(height: 100),
                Text('Can check biometrics: $_canCheckBiometrics\n'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Check biometrics'),
                  onPressed: _checkBiometrics,
                ),
                Divider(height: 100),
                Text('Available biometrics: $_availableBiometrics\n'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Get available biometrics'),
                  onPressed: _getAvailableBiometrics,
                ),
                Divider(height: 100),
                Text('Current State: $_authorized\n'),
                (_isAuthenticating)
                    ? ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _cancelAuthentication,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text("Cancel Authentication"),
                      Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                    : Column(
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Text('Authenticate'),
                          Icon(Icons.perm_device_information),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: _authenticate,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Text(_isAuthenticating
                              ? 'Cancel'
                              : 'Authenticate: biometrics only'),
                          Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: _authenticateWithBiometrics,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum _SupportState {
  unknown,
  supported,
  unsupported,
}
```